# Why did the First Amendment not override the Copyright Clause?

Tags: united-states, copyright, us-constitution, first-amendment

Why does the First Amendment not override the Copyright Clause, making copyright an unconstitutional violation of freedom of speech and press?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The Supreme Court generally treats the Copyright Clause and the First Amendment as complementary, not conflicting:

> The Copyright Clause and First Amendment were adopted close in time. This proximity indicates that, in the Framers' view, copyright's limited monopolies are compatible with free speech principles. Indeed, copyright's purpose is to promote the creation and publication of free expression. As [*Harper Row*](https://casetext.com/case/harper-row-publishers-inc-v-nation-enterprises) observed: "[T]he Framers intended copyright itself to be the engine of free expression. By establishing a marketable right to the use of one's expression, copyright supplies the economic incentive to create and disseminate ideas."

[*Eldred v. Ashcroft*, 537 U.S. 186, 219 (2003)](https://casetext.com/case/eldred-v-ashcroft).

Although the Court didn't remark on it, this treatment is also consistent with the canon called *generalia specialibus non derogant*, "the ancient interpretive principle that the specific governs the general." [*Nitro-Lift Techs., L.L.C. v. Howard*, 568 U.S. 17, 21 (2012)](https://casetext.com/case/nitro-lift-techs-llc-v-howard-2).

Here, the First Amendment supplies a rule that Congress may not abridge the freedom of press generally, but the Copyright Clause supplies a rule allowing Congress to abridge the right to use specific writings. The Copyright Clause is more specific, so it creates an exception to the First Amendment's general rule.

Comment: I find the logic of the **author being quoted** (not *your* logic!) rather twisted in claiming that an economic incentive is critical to create and disseminate ideas.  Usenet, StackExchange, and Reddit are good examples of why this is a questionable and dubious claim.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Note the date. 2003: Usenet was a channel primarily used by techies, StackExchange and Reddit didn't exist back then. To disseminate ideas on a wider scale, you needed books, newspapers and/or TV. All of which need an economic incentive to just exist. Your argument calls for a copyright reform because a new player (the internet) has entered the idea dissemination market, but the logic of the author being quoted was valid back then -- and even more valid back when the Copyright Clause was introduced.

Comment: @bdb484 Are you sure you pasted the links correctly? The "Eldred vs Ashcroft" link points to the same source as "Harper Row".

Comment: @orithena You're *(somewhat!)* right. The 2003 date had scrolled off my screen, and I saw the 2012 date for the second reference. Where I do disagree, however, is about Usenet. Usenet (and CompuServe & AOL) were widely used to discuss every topic imaginable. Yes, people using them often had at least a modicum of technical skill, but people of many walks of life used those services to create & disseminate ideas... without expressed copyright. And, of course, now there is Twitter & Facebook, but I'm not sure anything intelligent or worthwhile is ever disseminated on either of those services. :)

Comment: @RockPaperLz Stack is a for profit company... I think reddit is too. Usenet is dead, but maybe would be alive if there was economic incentive.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Still, the "new player" had not fully entered the idea dissemination market in 2003 ([Oct 2003, Internet access: 60% of US households](https://www.census.gov/data/tables/2003/demo/computer-internet/p23-208.html)). It was on the verge to become a player, and had not be proven as such in the minds of many people, so the argumentation of the author being quoted still was valid.

Comment: @orithena Humans existed back then. As did lending libraries which cost you nothing. Benjamin Franklin refused to patent any of his inventions precisely because he didn't want to limit the use of his ideas. No this isn't about promoting expression. It's about getting paid for it.

Comment: @608 Stack may be a for-profit company, but none of the contributors who write all the content (on which they make money) get paid anything.  But if you're somehow getting paid for your writings here, please do let us know how!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket I endorse the principle quoted, but not the application. I suspect that lots of great art might never have been created if the artists didn't think they could use it to pay their bills. But when that protection is extended beyond the artist's life and perhaps for a century or more, those incentives become less meaningful to anyone who is apt to create anything meaningful. I'm sure that sort of a thing is a nice incentive for a record label, but I suspect Bob Dylan would have written *Freewheelin'* even if he only had exclusive rights for 10 years.

Comment: @orithena Duly noted and fixed. Thanks.

Comment: @RockPaperLz Remember thjat the copyright clause dates from the late 1700s, and most of the intellectual justification for it from the early to mid 1800s. The current copyright act dates from 1976. Even in 2022 the majority of serious novels and works of non-fiction are created for pay, not distributes free of charge.  The theory is that economic incentives allow more people to be full-time or major part-time authors and thus allow a greater volume ads wider diversity of works to be created and published.

Comment: @RockPaperLz Do read Martk Twain's ["Petition Concerning Copyright"](https://americanliterature.com/author/mark-twain/short-story/petition-concerning-copyright) Twain thoguht the then-current term of 42 years ridiculously short, and unfair to authors. I don't agree with Twain's logic in full, and I think if he could see the "IP" scene of today he might modify his views. But it helps to give one perspective on the reasons behind longer copyright terms.

Comment: @bdb484 Perhaps Dylan would have. But many authors and artists support families on the proceeds of their creations and the ability to sell copyrights helps them to do so, when otherwise more might need day jobs. The length of copyright protection increases the current value of a copyright or a license, and thus adds to the rewards that an author can reap in the short term, to some extent at least. Dylan is not exactly your typical artist.

Comment: Whether the author of the anwers methods are conceptually in conflict with the answer is hardly relevant, the question is about the constitution and its interpretation, not ones personal feelings on it. (Personally, I think copyright belongs in the "It seemed like a good idea at the time" memory-hole, but I'm not the constition either)

Comment: @RockPaperLz I'm sorry, it's just not in the budget.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Thanks so much for that Mark Twain link. I've read so much of Twain's work, I'm surprised I've never read that particular piece. I'm also surprised he considered 42 years to be short, especially given the average lifespan when he was alive.  Related to this topic, there's a great bumper sticker (often found on guitar cases) that states: "REAL MUSICIANS HAVE DAY JOBS". :)

Comment: @608 Are you referencing Stack not paying contributors? Not sure if you are just joking or being serious, but if you're serious... Is the budget public? How much are the people being paid who created and approved this budget?

Comment: @RockPaperLz *facepalm* It's not in the budget [for *you* to make money posting on SE]. A joke.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Agreed. Extended rights of exclusivity are undoubtedly greater incentives for the original creator. And I like the idea of exclusivity for the creators of more pedestrian works, like ad copy or kitschy signs. The question (for me) is whether rolling back copyright protection to 10 or 20 years would, on balance, stifle or promote the creation of useful art. Because I question the artistic merit of any work the artist wants to hoard for 100 years, the answer feels obvious.

Comment: @608 I see your joke now... that's funny now that I understand it. ;)

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answers by bdb484 and AnoE (both of which I agree with), the Constitution is generally interpreted as a consistent whole, which does not contradict itself. The amendments are generally treated as **adding** to the Constitution, but not as "overriding" parts of it, except where they clearly or explicitly modify an existing provision. So the direct election of Senators changed the previous provision for their appointment by the state legislators. The separate election of the Vice-President replaced the earlier provision for Presidential elections. The amendment allowing an Income tax modified the previous (never used) provision for apportionment of direct taxes. But aside from these and a few similar cases where an amendment clearly or explicitly overrides a prior provision. amendments generally add to the constitutional fabric, but do not override existing provisions.

Answer (score 3):

**To answer the question...**

The government can pass copyright laws to restrict certain aspects of reproducing works with no issue regarding freedom of speech. In this particular case, keep in mind that copyright specifically protects *works* (in the technical sense), i.e., the concrete, physical formulation of text, images etc. - it says nothing about ideas, facts, opinions and such. Famously, algorithms, cooking recipes etc. cannot be copyrighted precisely because copyright does not apply to the factual content (only the representation). Freedom of Speech protects *speech*, *opinions* and such, so in a sense the exact opposite. As an example, copyright does not keep you from reading a book, and repeating the content in your own words. No conflict there.

Copyright would only protect speech in a very specific sense - i.e. if you have a recording of a particular speech or piece of literature etc.; that particular audio recording including the concrete choice of words (the "work") would be subject to Copyright. Everybody else would be totally free to say anything similar to that in their own words.

The same applies if you interpret "speech" independent of audio - i.e. you can absolutely take a book, reformulate every sentence in your own words, and publish it to your heart's content. As it is a completely different work, copyright would not be involved in that.

**Speaking more generally...**

This question shows a very common misunderstanding of what "free speech" in general, or the First Amendment of the US constitution is.

To quote the first sentence on the amendment in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution):

> The First Amendment (Amendment I) to the United States Constitution
> *prevents the government from making laws* that regulate an
> establishment of religion, or that prohibit the free exercise of
> religion, or abridge the freedom of speech, the freedom of the press,
> the freedom of assembly, or the right to petition the government for
> redress of grievances. It was adopted on December 15, 1791, as one of
> the ten amendments that constitute the Bill of Rights.

(Emphasis mine).

The focus of the 1st amendment is to *limit the right of the government* to pass certain laws. It is *not* a free-for-all pass for everybody to say everything.

In general terms, Freedom of Speech does not mean that everybody can just say anything at all at any point of time without repercussions.

In other words, to quote the more general entry on [Freedom of Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_speech), Freedom of Speech is *not* an "absolute" right but has to be seen in the context of what is being said by whom:

> Freedom of speech and expression, therefore, may not be recognized as
> being absolute, and common limitations or boundaries to freedom of
> speech relate to libel, slander, obscenity, pornography, sedition,
> incitement, fighting words, classified information, copyright
> violation, trade secrets, food labeling, non-disclosure agreements,
> the right to privacy, dignity, the right to be forgotten, public
> security, and perjury.

To recap: Freedom of Speech in the context of constitutions means that the *government* cannot restrict their citizens in very specific ways that would - basically - prevent citizens to express critique of the government, to voice their opinions, to assemble, and so on. One of the most important words in this is "government". It can be quite legal for other entities (companies, clubs etc.) or rulings (trade secrets etc.) to restrict said freedoms; sometimes even for the government (in the case of copyright, or classified information etc.).

Examples where no such freedom exists:

- Having active moderation in online forums etc. does not fall under the Freedom of Speech. For example, a forum about CPUs from company 1 could decide that they do not allow even mentioning CPUs from company 2 (for whatever reasons). A forum for runners could decide that asking medical or highly individual questions (with no benefit to anybody else) would be forbidden. Completely legal, both practically as well as philosophically; not related to Freedom of Speech whatsoever.
- Companies can regulate their employees to keep them from talking about internal topics with no limitations whatsoever (and often do, even for external entities like reporters, or subcontractors, in the form of NDAs).
- While lying is generally not considered a crime, in many countries you cannot write certain lies on the packaging of food (i.e. lies about the weight/volume of the contents, or the exact ingredients - they are still free to lie in other aspects, e.g. calling a food "healthy" which is clearly detrimental to many people, i.e. primarily sugar-water-based drinks).

Comment: " Freedom of Speech in the context of constitutions means that the government cannot restrict their citizens in _very specific_ ways". I think you got the inversion wrong. The government cannot restrict citiizens in _very broad ways_; it _can_ restrict them in very specific ways.

Comment: "Rulings" are only legal insomuch as they are authorized by laws and laws are not legal if they are proscribed by the Constitution. Copyright rulings are only possible because copyright law says they are. Copyright law is legal because the Constitution says it is and reasonable evaluation of the First Amendment and the discussion surrounding its passage shows that the framers did not in any way intend for it to effectively repeal the copyright clause.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137374/discussion-on-answer-by-anoe-why-did-the-first-amendment-not-override-the-copyri).

Comment: @reirab: Congress' authority over copyright is granted as the power to promote progress in the sciences and useful arts *by* granting exclusive rights to authors and inventors, which is a much tighter bounding of authority to purpose than most other powers.  The simultaneous binding of copyright to the lifetime of authors and its detachment from any requirement to make authors identifiable is either a calculated move to freeze progress or a result of such mindless recklessness that it deserves zero respect.  If copyright were 70 years, but could be extended to author's lifetime...

Comment: ...plus 70 years if a copyright holder registered the work in association with *the author whose lifetime would be measured* that would make sense, but making it impossible to know when 90% of works enter the public domain within 50 years of their doing so is incredibly inane.

Comment: @supercat replied in chat using the link above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a quip, one could summarize Eldred v. Ashcroft thusly:

**Because one can make money with copyrights, but not with free speech.**